# How to align buttons inside cards with different content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am still learning CSS and HTML. So please excuse me if this is a silly question.
Please see my code below. I need help with aligning the blue buttons on both the cards. It should be on the bottom of the cards (aligned similarly) regardless of content size.
Please advise.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  /* equal height of the children */
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.card-header {
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 31px 10px 31px 15px;
}

.card-header-bg {
  height: 7px;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
}

.blue-button,
a.blue-button {
  background-color: #026fc2;
  border-radius: 99rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #454545;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: rgba(255, 181, 119, 1);"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <p>Test Example</p>

      <ul>
        <li>test1</li>

        <li>test2</li>

        <li>test3</li>

        <li>test4</li>
      </ul>

      <p>Minor updates.</p>

      <ul>
        <li>test</li>

        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

      <p><a href=".html" class="blue-button" role="button" style=" float: right; margin-bottom: 30px;">Go Here</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: #7ECEFD;"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <p>test123/p>

        <ul>
          <li>abc</li>

          <li>def</li>

          <li>ghi</li>
        </ul>

        <p>test test test.</p>

        <ul>
          <li>Learn about testing</li>
        </ul>

        <p><a href="" class="blue-button" role="button" style=" float: right; margin-bottom: 30px;">Second Test</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a silly question. They seem unaligned because there are more `li`'s on the left side. Buttons are positioned `statically` by default, so if there is more content, it will be pushed down. You'll notice if you add more `li`'s on the right side, the button will be pushed down and seem aligned. You may find nesting the `buttons` in their own `divs` will give you more control.

However, you can easily resolve this with your current structure by adding `<br>` or the [line-break element](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/lbreak.html) on the button that is positioned higher. See below.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  /* equal height of the children */
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.card-header {
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 31px 10px 31px 15px;
}

.card-header-bg {
  height: 7px;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blue-button,
a.blue-button {
  background-color: #026fc2;
  border-radius: 99rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #454545;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-primary {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card-container>div {
  height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: rgba(255, 181, 119, 1);"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <div>
        <p>Test Example</p>

        <ul>
          <li>test1</li>

          <li>test2</li>

          <li>test3</li>

          <li>test4</li>
        </ul>

        <p>Minor updates.</p>

        <ul>
          <li>test</li>

          <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-primary">
      <a href=".html" class="blue-button" role="button">Go Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: #7ECEFD;"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <div>
        <p>test123</p>

        <ul>
          <li>abc</li>

          <li>def</li>

          <li>ghi</li>
        </ul>

        <p>test test test.</p>

        <ul>
          <li>Learn about testing</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-primary">
      <a href="" class="blue-button" role="button">Second Test</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Largest rendered height at default ~ makes height for both divs.

[image]

Comment: Line breaks should not be used for visual positioning.

Comment: Thanks, I added line break and it looks fine for now. But I am worried that if the content on the card changes, I will run into this problem again. Is there a way for the buttons to align all the time regardless of the content inside the card?

Comment: @Superman yes, you should nest your `buttons` in `divs` and use `flex`

Comment: Thanks, Can you please let me know how to do it. Like I mentioned, I am very new to css and html (beginner level). Thanks.

Comment: @Superman @Sean see edits. I flexed `card-container` and also re-structured your markup a bit.

Comment: @ カメロン Thankyou very much!!

Comment: Update: I had to remove container height as the content in the boxes were not looking good in responsive. Content was overlapping on header. Is there a way around this? Removing height now doesn't keep the buttons down on the bottom of the box.

Comment: @Superman nest the other `card-container` contents in another div, and check which div has the longest rendered height, for example, in your case is the left div since it has more `li`'s. Then you can adjust the height of that div by adding `.card-container > div { height: ~;}`. Just extend your height to be larger when you add more content. See edits.

Comment: Thanks カメロン
I adjusted the height to 75% to accommodate for longest height content. The problem is it pushes the content down for the card with less content (creating white space on top) and the button also overflows outside of the container for both the cards. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Superman Just add `height: 210px;` on `card-container > div` and make it larger each time you add more bullet points or more content. This includes nesting a your `card-container` contents in a non-flexed div. Look at the edits in both the HTML and CSS. This should work for you!

Comment: This worked!! Thankyou very much!!

Comment: On another note, how can I stack the boxes in responsive. I want these boxes to be stacked as rows instead of 2 columns. Please let me know if I need to open a new question for this. Thankyou! It is for the same HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Superman Post a new question ~ I will be on the look for it.

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129918/how-to-stack-flex-box-in-responsive
Thankyou!