# How to stack flex box in responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am still learning CSS, html and concepts of responsive design. Can someone can please help me to stack these boxes as rows in responsive instead of columns. Please see the code below.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  /* equal height of the children */
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.card-header {
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 31px 10px 31px 15px;
}

.card-header-bg {
  height: 7px;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
}

.blue-button,
a.blue-button {
  background-color: #026fc2;
  border-radius: 99rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #454545;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: rgba(255, 181, 119, 1);"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <p>Test Example</p>

      <ul>
        <li>test1</li>

        <li>test2</li>

        <li>test3</li>

        <li>test4</li>
      </ul>

      <p>Minor updates.</p>

      <ul>
        <li>test</li>

        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

      <p><a href=".html" class="blue-button" role="button" style=" float: right; margin-bottom: 30px;">Go Here</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: #7ECEFD;"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <p>test123/p>

        <ul>
          <li>abc</li>

          <li>def</li>

          <li>ghi</li>
        </ul>

        <p>test test test.</p>

        <ul>
          <li>Learn about testing</li>
        </ul>

        <p><a href="" class="blue-button" role="button" style=" float: right; margin-bottom: 30px;">Second Test</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They appear as rows for me already. Do you want them stacked one on top of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `margin` on `col1` and use `flex-direction: column;` on your `row`.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* equal height of the children */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {  
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .col1 {
    margin: 0px !important;
  }
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1;
  /* additionally, equal width */
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}


.card-header {
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 31px 10px 31px 15px;
}

.card-header-bg {
  height: 7px;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
}

.blue-button,
a.blue-button {
  background-color: #026fc2;
  border-radius: 99rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #454545;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: rgba(255, 181, 119, 1);"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <p>Test Example</p>

      <ul>
        <li>test1</li>

        <li>test2</li>

        <li>test3</li>

        <li>test4</li>
      </ul>

      <p>Minor updates.</p>

      <ul>
        <li>test</li>

        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

      <p><a href=".html" class="blue-button" role="button" style=" float: right; margin-bottom: 30px;">Go Here</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <div class="card-header-bg" style=" background-color: #7ECEFD;"></div>

    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <p>test123</p>

        <ul>
          <li>abc</li>

          <li>def</li>

          <li>ghi</li>
        </ul>

        <p>test test test.</p>

        <ul>
          <li>Learn about testing</li>
        </ul>

        <p><a href="" class="blue-button" role="button" style=" float: right; margin-bottom: 30px;">Second Test</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit ~ Image of `flex-direction: row;` with `gap`. Resembles margin you had set initially.

[image]

Edit ~ added `media-query` to have div's stack when resizing. Also, put back in your `margin` for the row/desktop view on IE, but removed the margin once the div's stack.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {  
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .col1 {
    margin: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. But, I need margin as I still want the boxes as columns in desktop view with a gap in between. I tried to use "gap property" but it does not work on IE. So ended up using margin. I want them stacked as rows only in responsive view (maybe less than 600px).

Comment: @Superman no problem! You don't need margin, just set `gap` on `.row` This will work either flex-direction ~ row or column, to separate the two divs. See edits.

Comment: @Superman see `media-query` I set so that the div's stack when resizing right at `600px`.

Comment: Thankyou. I tried what you said and it works fine on chrome browser. However, gap does not work on IE. Thats why I ended up using margin earlier. Is there a workaround to gap?

Comment: @Superman see most recent edit - should be good now!

Comment: Thankyou very much カメロン . This worked!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242042/discussion-between--and-superman).